# Configuration Of Messageboxes in Python

Tags: python, tkinter

I am working on a Library Management Software . I am successfully able to insert a Messagebox. I want to configure it and make it black in colour like the following image:-
https://images.app.goo.gl/TsXZX3nqCpYssqoTA

I am not able to get the appropriate code. 
This was the code that I have tried
    messagebox.showinfo("TIMINGS","WELCOME TO THE CENTRAL LIBRARY                                       OPENS AT 09:00                                                                        CLOSES AT 15:00")
Thank You for your help

Comment: Show us what have you tried so far?

Comment: https://www.devdungeon.com/content/dialog-boxes-python
https://datatofish.com/message-box-python/
https://www.homeandlearn.uk/file-dialog-boxes.html.             These are the websites that I have visited and I tried my best to modify the dialog Box . Therefore it would be appreciated if you help me . Thanks in advance

Comment: I think you misunderstood. I meant [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/62197766/edit) this question and add a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: I have written the code. It would be very kind of you if you could solve my problem. Thank You in advance

Comment: Unfortunately, the code you've posted is not a [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), as we can't use it to exactly reproduce your problem. Please give the minimum amount of code required for this problem to manifest